# Font usage and number display by xlop

Tags: fonts, xetex, formatting, xlop

Here is my sample code, for some reason the font changes for all the text except the actual math problems (as highlighted). How should I get the xlop to use the font set in setmainfont. Any insight on how this works will be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[20pt,fleqn,leqno]{extarticle}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xlop}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xlop

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Goudy Stout}

\begin{document}

Math worksheet

\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)}]
\item { \opadd[style=text] {61}{7} }
\item {\opadd[style=text] {1}{7} }
\item {\opadd[style=text] {161}{7} }
\item {\opadd[style=text] {1}{700} }
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don’t have Goudy Stout to experiment with, but have you tried the `mathspec` package?

Comment: I have not tried mathspec, I will look into it. I am using 'Goudy Stout' as a sample to illustrate, it could be any font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\opadd[style=text]` uses by default the math font and without this option the text font. When compiling with LuaLaTeX, these fonts can be modified with `\fontspec` and `\setmathfont`.

```
    % !TeX program = lualatex
    \documentclass{article}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448989/font-usage-and-number-display-by-xlop
    \usepackage{xlop}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \setmainfont{Segoe Print}%<-- if comment Latin Modern »
    \setmathfont{Erewhon Math}%<-- if comment Latin Modern Math 
    \begin{document}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        \begin{center}
            By default
        \end{center}
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)}]
    \item {\opadd[style=text] {61}{7}}
    \item {\opadd {61}{7} }
    \item \opidiv{17}{6}
    %\item $\opidiv{17}{6}$ <-- mode math aucun effet
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}%
        \vrule
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        \begin{center}
            With modification
        \end{center}
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)}]
    \item {\setmathfont{Segoe Print}\opadd[style=text] {61}{7}\setmathfont{Erewhon Math}}
    %\item $1+2=3$
    \item {\fontspec{Erewhon Math}\opadd {61}{7}}
    \item {\fontspec{Erewhon Math}\opidiv{17}{6}}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}%

    \bigskip
    Some text and $1+2=3$
    \end{document}
```

[image]